# Cuál es la alternativa de @api.one en Odoo 14?

Tags: python, xml, odoo, openerp, odoo13

Estoy migrando unos módulos de la versión de Odoo **12** a la versión **14**, sin embargo, acabo de enterarme de algunos de los decoradores fueron retirados desde la versión **13** por lo que algunas funciones que tengo con el decorador **@api.one** y **@api.multi** ya no funcionan de la misma forma ya que al intentar ejecutarlas me aparece el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**¿Cuál sería la alternativa a estos decoradores?**

Adjunto las funciones que tengo hasta ahora

```
#@api.one
@api.depends('marketplace_order_id')
#@api.onchange('marketplace_order_id')
def _compute_display_order_id(self):
    if self.marketplace_order_id:
        if len(str(self.marketplace_order_id)) > 20:
            self.dsp_marketplace_order_id = str(self.marketplace_order_id)[0:20]+'...'
        else:
            self.dsp_marketplace_order_id = self.marketplace_order_id
    else:
        self.dsp_marketplace_order_id = 'Venta Piso'

#@api.one
@api.depends('etiqueta_meli')
#@api.onchange('marketplace_order_id')
def _display_etiqueta(self):
    seller_name = str(self.seller_marketplace)
    token = str(self.env['tokens_markets.tokens_markets'].search([('seller_name', '=', seller_name)]).access_token)
    if self.etiqueta_meli:
        self.dsp_etiqueta_meli = str(self.etiqueta_meli)+ token
    else:
        self.dsp_etiqueta_meli = 'Sin Etiqueta'

_sql_constraints = [
('marketplace_order_id_uniq', 'unique(marketplace_order_id)', "El Id de la Orden de Venta de Mercado Libre ya existe!"),
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Desde la versión 13 todos los decoradores se han quitado (@api.multi, @api.returns, @api.one, @api.cr, @api.model_cr). Ahora mismo son todos multi-record por defecto.

Ahora mismo lo que tines que hacer es recorer la clase como se suele hacer:

```
for rec in self:
   custom code
```

Si tú funcion solo puede recoger un registro y va a devolver una sola acción basada en un solo record tienes que poner al principio de la funcion lo siguente:

```
self.ensure_one()
```